# Making Textbox type into a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, text, textbox, button, submit

I'm a noob to VB.NET and I was wondering how to make something you type into a textbox on the application type that text into a website textbox and submit whats in the textbox by pressing a button? I am using visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

That is a little tricky to do, but it is possible. However, without more details on the specific browser or what you are trying to copy over, you aren't going to get a lot of answers on here.

Better Suggestion: Have you considered instead of trying to control the browser via "voodoo", that you might just have your VB.NET application submit the form/request directly to the web server and cut out the middle-man (the browser)?

Comment: the application actually contains a web browser and i am just trying to make an external textbox because the box on the website is all the wasy at the bottom of the page and i want to make it easy to access

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to POST data to a web form from some other application.  Check [this](http://www.doachick.com/development/c-tutorials/62-c-submiting-and-manipulating-web-forms) out; it's in C# but you can translate it to VB.NET.  It uses a WebBrowser control and the SetAttribute method to set input values on the web form.

```
// C#
WebBrowser browser;
...
browser.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "MyUsername");
...
form.InvokeMember("submit");
```